# Importing large number of pdfs into mPDF is causing /fopen to fail

Tags: php, mpdf

Edit: Updated after assistance from Jan

Edit: The code dos not fail until $mpdf->Output($max . ' imports .pdf', 'D'); is called

PHP Version 7.1

MPDF Version 8.0.10

Setasign fpdi_pdf-parser Version 2.0.4
Error

> Failed to open file (fopen) Compnay Induction (checklist) th v2.pdf
> Failed to open file (fopen) Information Register for Employees.pdf
> Failed to open file (fopen) Coshh listings v7.pdf Failed to open file
> (fopen) Emp Competency Form.pdf

Below is a snippet of my code which produces the error

```
function addCustomForms($forms, $mpdf, $Customer)
{
    if ($forms) {
        $handles = [];
        foreach ($forms as $CustomPolicyForm) {
            if (is_file('../cdata/' . $Customer->reference . '/policy-forms/' . $CustomPolicyForm->form)) {
                try {
                    $h = \fopen('../cdata/' . $Customer->reference . '/policy-forms/' . $CustomPolicyForm->form, 'rb');
                    // File not Opened
                    if ($h === false) {
                            echo 'Failed to open file (fopen) ' . $CustomPolicyForm->form . '<br/>';
                            return false;
                        } else {

                        $stream = new \setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader($h, false);
                        $pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile($stream);
                        if ($pagecount > 0) {
                            for ($i = 1; $i <= ($pagecount); $i++) {
                                $mpdf->AddPage($CustomPolicyForm->orientation);
                                if ($i == 1) {
                                    $html = '<h3 style="color: #ffffff;">' . sd($CustomPolicyForm->title) . '</h3>';
                                    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
                                }
                                try {
                                    $import_page = $mpdf->importPage($i);
                                    try {
                                        $mpdf->useTemplate($import_page);

                                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                                        echo 'Not worked for ' . $CustomPolicyForm->title .'<br/>';
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception $e) {
                                    echo 'importPage failed for ' . $CustomPolicyForm->title . ' Page ' . $i .'<br/>';
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            $handles[] = $h;

                        } else {
                            echo 'Page count is less than 1 for ' . $CustomPolicyForm->form .'<br/>';
                            return false;

                        }
                    }
                } catch
                (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Failed to set source file for ' . $CustomPolicyForm->form . '<br/>';
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                echo 'File not found: ' . $CustomPolicyForm->form .'<br/>';
                return false;
            }
            $pagecount = null;
        }
        return $handles;

    } else {
        // No forms found
        echo 'No Forms Found';
        return false;
    }
}

$mpdf->Output(Customer::find_by_id($Policy->customer_id)->customer . '.pdf', 'D');
        \fclose($handles);
```

Changing TOCuseLinking' => false hides/resolves the issue but I am not sure what is causing the issue in the first place.

The test file I am using is https://1drv.ms/b/s!ApXTTaxD_QQPj7kwpxX3G4a5-2Ir2Q?e=WJRMi3 (This is a blank PDF)

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TOC functionalitiy of mPDF tries to do some magic by cloning the whole instance and resetting it... I didn't digged deeper into it. But by this the references to the stream readers are unset. Due to the amount of objects the garbadge collector is triggered later which triggers the `__destruct()` method which closes the stream handle then.

To bypass this issue you need to get control over the file handle. Your example can be rewritten like this:

```
$h = \fopen('BLANK PDF.pdf', 'rb');
$stream = new \setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader($h, false);

for ($count = 0; $count < $max; $count++) {
    $pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile($stream);
    if ($pagecount > 0) {
        $mpdf->AddPage();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($pagecount); $i++) {
            if ($i == 1) {
                $html = '<h3 style="color: #000;">' . htmlentities('Blank PDF ' . $count) . '</h3>';
                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
            }
            $import_page = $mpdf->importPage($i);
            $mpdf->useTemplate($import_page);

        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
$mpdf->Output($max . ' imports .pdf', 'F');

fclose($h);
```

If you need to work with different files, store the handles in an array to keep their references.

You should also notice that the operation system have a limit on open file handles. FPDI is bound to this limit.

Comment: Thank you for your assistane Jan.

It still hasn't worked for me though. I've updated the code above with the function that I am calling and the error (set by me so I can see where it is occuring).

Comment: You open and close the handle in your foreach() loop, which is, for sure, wrong! You also instruct the reader instance to close the handle automatically (snd parameter needs to be false!) when it get unset... I don't see a call to `Output()` at all? All file handles needs to be kept until `Output()` is called. As written in my answer you should collect them in an array.

Comment: Thanks again Jan.

I'm return the handles into an array now and amended the code to be false. I'm thinking about how I can get the function to open the handle out side of the foreach loop. 

Interestingly, If the PDFs being included are just text (added a 14 page text only pdf), the code works, or if I reduce the number of filees being imported, it also works. It fails with 38 but works with 32. With 38, I get the infinite loop error again.

Apologies I am a bit slow with this.

Comment: The more data is handled that earlier the [GC](https://php.net/gc) is triggered. Your array may be also collected from the GC because it is only used in the function scope. Make sure that you hold references to the file handles as long as the PDF generation is done.

Comment: Jan my friend you are a star! The GC was causing me the error and using gc_collect_cycles(); (whether it's right or not!) has fixed my issue! 

Many thanks for your persistance with my issues and I.

Comment: Calling it is definitively wrong. The error is caused because it runs! Harden your references to the file handles and they should not be collected. That's it :-)